# obtener el numero de la posicion de la columna donde la suma acumulativa por columnas cumpla cierto valor (en R)

Tags: r

tengo este dataframe:

`bd <- data.frame(a=c(3,5,"","",1),b=c("",3,"","",2),c=c(3,"","","",3),d=c(1,"","",5,4))`

el cual da como resultado:

```
a  b  c  d
3     3  1 
5  3

         5
1  2  3  4
```

Lo que necesito hacer es crear una nueva variable en el que obtenga la posicion de la columna, el cual cumpla que la suma acumulada por filas sea mayor o igual a 5 por primera vez

Deberia obtener algo asi:

```
a  b  c  d  N_V
3     3  1   3   ## N_V=3 es la posicion de la columna c (ya que 3+3>=5)
5  3         1
             0
         5   4
1  2  3  4   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar, no sé si tu ejemplo es representativo, es rara la forma que lo defines:

```
bd <- data.frame(a=c(3,5,"","",1),b=c("",3,"","",2),c=c(3,"","","",3),d=c(1,"","",5,4))
```

Básicamente por dos razones: **(a)** Al usar `""` para indicar ausencia de valor estás coercionando la columna para que sea una cadena y no un número y **(b)** la función `data.frame()` tiene un comportamiento por defecto, para algunos cuestionable, que trata a las cadenas como factores.

Como necesitamos tratar todas las columnas como numéricas, debemos reconvertir los datos mediante:

```
bd <- apply(bd, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) {as.numeric(as.character(x))})
bd

      a  b  c  d
[1,]  3 NA  3  1
[2,]  5  3 NA NA
[3,] NA NA NA NA
[4,] NA NA NA  5
[5,]  1  2  3  4
```

Básicamente transformamos cada columna en una cadena (por que en realidad ya es un factor) y luego a un numérico. El resultado final es una matriz numérica, donde `NA` es la ausencia de un valor. Todo esto se podría simplificar si el ejemplo se definiera así:

```
bd <- data.frame(a=c(3,5,NA,NA,1),b=c(NA,3,NA,NA,2),c=c(3,NA,NA,NA,3),d=c(1,NA,NA,5,4))
```

#### Ahora sí vamos a tu pregunta:

Una forma muy sencilla es verificar la suma acumulada por fila y entonces verificar la posición del primer valor que supere nuestro límite, por ejemplo:

```
cumsum(ifelse(is.na(bd[1, ]),0,bd[1, ]))
[1]  3  3  6  7 10
```

Con esto tenemos la suma acumulada de la fila 1, hay que tener precaución con los valores `NA`, por lo que con el `ifelse()` transformamos estos en 0 para poder completar el `cumsum()`, y por último para saber que posición es la del primer valor que cumpla la condición podemos agregar el uso del `which()`:

```
which(cumsum(ifelse(is.na(bd[1, ]),0,bd[1, ]))>=5)[1]
[1] 3
```

Para la primer fila, la columna 3 es la que cumple la condición. Ahora solo resta transformar todo en una función y aplicarla iterativamente sobre cada fila:

```
bd$N_V <- apply(bd, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {which(cumsum(ifelse(is.na(x),0,x))>=5)[1]})

bd
   a  b  c  d N_V
1  3 NA  3  1   3
2  5  3 NA NA   1
3 NA NA NA NA  NA
4 NA NA NA  5   4
5  1  2  3  4   3
```